# alert after second option is selected using javascript and html

Tags: javascript, html

Good day, I am a newbie using javascript .
This is how the code works: Drop drown select/option(tan) populates the second option(action) assigned . My problem is after second option(action) is selected the alert doesn't show... Please kindly help me. thanks in advance

```html
<html>
<head><title>wahaha</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $("#type").change
    (function ()
{
var val = $(this).val();
if (val == "tan") 
{
 $("#size").html("<select id='m'><option value='test'>nope</option><option value='action'>action</option></select>");
if (val == "action") 
{   
    window.alert(5 + 6);
}
else if (val == test) 
            {   
                window.alert(5 + 6);
            }
            else{   alert("sample code"); }
        } 

         else if (val == "-- select one --") 
        {
            $("#size").html("<option value='test'>disney</option><option value='test2'>disneyt</option>");


        } 
        else if (val == "green") 
        {
            $("#size").html("<option value='test'>olive</option><option value='test2'>mantis green</option><option value='test2'>jungle green</option><option value='test'>asparagus</option>");

        }
        else if (val == "blue") 
        {
            $("#size").html("<option value='test'>azure</option><option value='test2'>cerulean</option>");
        }

}
    );
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>

<select id="type">
        <option value="-- select one --">-- select one -- </option>
        <option value="tan">tan</option>
        <option value="green">green</option>
        <option value="blue">blue</option>

</select>
<select id="size">
    <option value="">-SIZE -- </option>
    <option value="">size </option>
    </select>
<br><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<html>
<head><title>wahaha</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#type").on("change",function(){
    // #type Select is selected

    var val = $(this).val();

    if(val == "tan")
        $("#size").html("<option value='test'>nope</option><option value='action'>action</option>");
    else if(val == "-- select one --")
        $("#size").html("<option value='test'>disney</option><option value='test2'>disneyt</option>");
    else if(val == "green")
        $("#size").html("<option value='test'>olive</option><option value='test2'>mantis green</option><option value='test2'>jungle green</option><option value='test'>asparagus</option>");
    else if(val == "blue")
        $("#size").html("<option value='test'>azure</option><option value='test2'>cerulean</option>");
    });

    $("#size").change(function(){
    // #size Select is selected

    var val2 = $(this).val();

    if(val2 == "action")
        alert( 5  + 6 );
    else if(val2 == "test")
        alert("sample code");
    });


});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>

<select id="type">
        <option value="-- select one --">-- select one -- </option>
        <option value="tan">tan</option>
        <option value="green">green</option>
        <option value="blue">blue</option>

</select>
<select id="size">
    <option value="">-SIZE -- </option>
    <option value="">size </option>
    </select>
<br><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

"action" value in #size select. So dont run. But it running now..

Answer (score 0):

**Your issue is not because of any if error as suggested in the other answer**.

Your issue is because the `change` function never triggers for the second drop down aka the one with the id `#side`.

> What you need to do?

You need to add the `click` listener to listen to a subsequent change in the value of `#size`  and then trigger an alert.

**DEMO**

Here is a [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/ETH1rwzBEJtnLRPSzi59?p=preview) of what you need to do.Feel free to add the conditions as per your requirements.The current condition works on selecting action.

Answer (score 0):

Please use alert() instead of window.alert().

```
 alert(5 + 6);
```

Please also check below

```
 else if (val == 'test') instead of else if (val == test)
```

This will resolve your problem.